# Python script that uses pycharm's refactoring methods

Tags: python, scripting, refactoring, pycharm

I am trying to create a script that will do the following.

- Iterate over each file in project.
- _Iterate over each method in the file.
- __if some_condition(method_name):
- ___user PyCharm's refactoring system to refactor the given method.

Couldn't find any reference to the above.
Does not request a given script(though wouldn't mind), any reference and start guidance would be welcome.

Using 
python 2.7
PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm is written in Java. There is no way to invoke PyCharm's refactoring system from a Python script.

Instead, you can write a plugin for PyCharm in Java, and implement that logic through PyCharm's plugin API.

Comment: Thanks, saved me time.